# Export all Azure AD Groups and their owner to a csv file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I need a way to export all Azure Ad groups with their corresponding owner to a csv file. The below code works, but the formatting of the csv file is horrendous. Everything is in one column and hard to read. How would I get all groups in one Column and the corresponding owner in a separate column in the corresponding row. Any help would be appreciated

```
 $groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
    ForEach ($group in $groups){
        $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
        ForEach ($Owner in $Owners){ 
            Write-output $group.DisplayName "," $Owner.ObjectId "," $Owner.ObjectType $Owner.UserType "," $Owner.UserPrincipalName >> C:\scripts\Owner.csv
        }
    }
```

Updated Script

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Foreach($group in $groups){

     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $id  -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName

     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){

                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 


        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$null
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  



     }

}
$array | export-csv -Path C:\test1234.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your need, you can refer to the following script:

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Foreach($group in $groups){
  $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
  ForEach ($Owner in $Owners){ 
            $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
            $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
            $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
            $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
            $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
            $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
            $array +=$obj 
  }
  

}


$array | export-csv -Path E:\test123.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

[image]

---

### Update

According to your need, I update my PowerShell script

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Foreach($group in $groups){
     
     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
            
     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){
    
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 
    
    
        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$null
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  
 
 
 
     }

}
$array | export-csv -Path E:\test123.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, the formatting of this is perfect and it runs great. My only problem is that it is only displaying the results of groups with owners. Only about 5-10% of our groups have owners. Is there any way to get groups without owners as well?

Comment: @mitchjay, could you tell me what is "Is there any way to get groups without owners as well?"? Is that you want to get the groups which do not have owners?

Comment: Yeah I would like to get groups that don't have owners as well

Comment: @mitchjay I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: I receive a couple hundred of these errors: At line:3 char:48
+      $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $id  -All $true
+                                                ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureADGroupOwner], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGr
   oupOwners

Comment: @mitchjay, could you please provide the script you use?

Comment: @mitchjay, according to the error, please try to run the command``` $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true``` in the foreach loop.

Comment: Where exactly am I putting that sorry?

Comment: @mitchjay, I update my PowerShell script. Please check it.

Comment: one last question sorry. Do you know the attribute for listing what type of group it is? e.g. Security, Distrubution or Office. ObjectType seems to only display that it is a group

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a proper CSV file with headers and rows of data, you need to collect an array of **Objects** and send that to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$result = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | ForEach-Object {
        # output an object with the properties and headernames you need
        # the $_ automatic variable contains 1 owner object in each iteration
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Group'     = $group.DisplayName
            'OwnerId'   = $_.ObjectId
            'OwnerType' = $_.ObjectType
            'OwnerUPN'  = $_.UserPrincipalName
        }
    }
} 

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\scripts\AZGroupOwners.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for the help. Unfortunately I receive this error after the 3 }.     
Get-AzureADGroupOwner : Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.
At line:2 char:5
+     Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | ForE ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADGroupOwner], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroupOwners

Comment: @mitchjay That error sounds like you have a corrupted PowerShellProperties.json file..  Do you also get the error if you hardcode the group's ObjectId there?