# Export AzureAD group owners to CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, export, usergroups, owner

The end goal I'm after is I want to have a csv containing the owners of all AzureAD groups.

I'm not well versed in PS and I've been trying to crack it for a while now, with various different scripts each with their own method. Things that seem logical, and I think would work, don't.

Feel free to edit what I've got or write a new script entirely, but please explain what you have done so I can learn :)

The closest I've come to what I want is using the below. But the caveat is if there are multiple owners of the group, each owner is listed out on separate rows and so there is also duplicate group names. I would like to have the group name in one column then all the owners in the next, seperated by " ,".

I tried using -join on the final line but it returns blank results.

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerDisplayName","2")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object DisplayName -Like "*Guest*" | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
Foreach($group in $groups){
     
     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
            
     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){
    
                $Properties.OwnerDisplayName=$Owner.DisplayName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 
    
    
        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerDisplayName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  
 
 
 
     }

}
$array | export-csv -Path C:\Temp\test123.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Thanks in advance for your help, you will save me some hair...

EDIT
This is another route I've tried. It does return results I want if using one specific ObjectID but I can't get it to loop the bunch of ObjectIds from step 1 and run the command for each one.

```
#Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

#Successfully returns groups with "Guest" in DisplayName
$GroupSearch = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object DisplayName -Like "*Guest*" | Select-Object ObjectId, DisplayName | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
$groups = @($GroupSearch | Select-Object ObjectID)


#Now to loop ObjectIDs from STEP 1 to lookup command
$Result = foreach ($group in $groups){
    Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId "$group" | Select-Object DisplayName
}

$Result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\AzureADgroupOwners.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Disconnect from AzureAD
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Comment: EDIT This is another route I've tried. It does return results I want if using one specific ObjectID but I can't get it to loop the bunch of ObjectIds from step 1 and run the command for each one.

Comment: powershell - Export all Azure AD Groups and their owner to a csv file by Jim Xu
Just FYI - the post titled above is where I got the first script from, I've just narrowed it down to give me only what I need. However, it gives me owners for the same group on individual rows. I need all the owners on the same row so 1 row per group.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with some help from other sources. Hopefully someone will find this helpful in future! This is how:

```
#Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

$Properties=@{}
$matchingOwners=@()
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object DisplayName -Like "*Guest*" 

Foreach($group in $groups) {
    
     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $matchingGroup = $group.DisplayName
           
     if ($null -ne $Owners) {
       #group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners) {

                $matchingOwners+=$Owner.DisplayName
        }
     } 
     $joinedOwners = $matchingOwners -join ", "
     $Properties.add($matchingGroup, $joinedOwners)
     $joinedOwners=""
     $matchingOwners=@()

}

$Properties.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property Key,Value | Sort-Object -Property Key | export-csv -Path C:\Temp\test123.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

#Disconnect from AzureAD
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment by using the below PowerShell script:***

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Foreach($group in $groups){
  $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
  ForEach ($Owner in $Owners){ 
            $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
            $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
            $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
            $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
            $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
            $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
            $array +=$obj 
  }
  }
$array | export-csv -Path YourPath.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

**The above script got executed successfully as below:**

[image]

**The CSV file was exported with the Azure Ad Group and Group owner details like below:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[powershell - Export all Azure AD Groups and their owner to a csv file by Jim Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870231/export-all-azure-ad-groups-and-their-owner-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks but that is where I got my script from, I've just narrowed it down to give me only what I need. As I said, it gives me owners for the same group on individual rows. I need all the owners on the same row.